# regular Expression to detect base64

Tags: python, regex, base64

I read an article about a regular expression to detect base64 but when I try it in "yara python" it gives an error of "unterminated regular expression"
the regular expression is:

> (?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}){2,}(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]=|[A-Za-z0-9+/][AQgw]==)

could anyone throw a suggestion please?
thanks

Comment: Why don't you just try to convert it to hex (or anything else). If it fails then you know it's not base64.

Comment: re.compile("(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}){2,}(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]=|[A-Za-z0-9+/][AQgw]==)") works like a charm, nothing wrong with the regex itself. Also, as Ben already mentioned, just decode it, see if it throws an error.

Comment: What should this expression atucally do? It doesn't match any string that's base64 encoded but only some very special ones...

Comment: well it detects base64 but misses on a few, according to the article it misses one out of three, it is supposed to have very few false positives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest escaping `/` character in the `[A-Za-z0-9+/]` block, because while unescaped it defines regular expression start/end.

Comment: No, Python doesn't use delimiters around regexes.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile(r'(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}){2,}(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]=|[A-Za-z0-9+/][AQgw]==)')
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x2865c40>
```

Comment: Thank you all, you have been awesome, I indeed tried it again and finally realized it was running well in python as you mentioned but giving error on "yara". Cheers everyone :)